# How to make tasks in Overview Screen looks like together like Chrome?

Tags: android

[image: Google tabs looks together]

These Google tabs looks together.

I tried, but it doesn't work.
intent flags I tried
 `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT`
 `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` 
`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, ***.class);
intent.addFlags(***);
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.AppTask> appTasks = activityManager.getAppTasks();
ActivityManager.AppTask appTask = appTasks.get(0);
appTask.startActivity(mActivity, intent, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, .class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(intent,
        ActivityOptions.makeTaskLaunchBehind().toBundle());
```

Comment: Please also add an explanation to your answer and don't just paste some code, as it can be hard to understand what exactly it is that you are doing.